# UseRowNumberForPaging is not a valid

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm using `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final"` with `SQL 2008` and according to some results found on Google, I just have to add the option to `.UseRowNmberForPaging()` when creating a new `DBcontext`. This was the solution for `rc1-final` but it doesn't seem to work for `rc2-final`.

When I add the option when configuring my service, it's not recognized.

Trying to paginate records on `SQL Server 2008` with `EF Core` so this seems to be the recommended solution.

Here is the line I'm using to Configure the service:

```
services.AddDbContext<Data.Models.AC_MCLContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(connection).UseRowNumberForPaging());
```

Does anyone know how to use the row number for paging in EntityFramework Core rc2?

Comment: Reordering a bit and formatting

Comment: What using clauses doe you have?

Answer (score 25):

A solution was given to me on another forum so I thought I'd share the answer in case anyone else ran into this issue.

The API now uses a nested closure pattern so the options should be configured as a nested structure like the example below.

```
        services.AddDbContext<Data.Models.AC_MCLContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(connection, 
               opt => opt.UseRowNumberForPaging()));
```

Answer (score 5):

This can also be done from the context itself.

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
           optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(yourConnectionStringValue, opt=>opt.UseRowNumberForPaging());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using EF Core 6 onward with SQL Server 2008, you can install the package below.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.UseRowNumberForPaging/

After installing the package, in Program.cs add:

```
using EntityFrameworkCore.UseRowNumberForPaging;
```

Then replace your DbContext service configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

by:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, 
        o => o.UseRowNumberForPaging()));
```