# .Net Core AddDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I has the following codes in my AddDbContext.

```
            services.AddDbContext<RewardsContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MembershipContext"),
                b => b.UseRowNumberForPaging(), sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(60)), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

But how can I include sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(60) in my line of codes as well? It keep giving me error. I suspected there's typo error.

Comment: You should include the error message you get in your question.

Comment: Please also include the version of EF Core nugets you're using.

Comment: It stated "No overload for method UseSqlServer takes 3 arguments.

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403188/userownumberforpaging-is-not-a-valid ?

Comment: Also this one marks that option as obsolete: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.sqlserverdbcontextoptionsbuilder.userownumberforpaging?view=efcore-3.1

Comment: Inside your DbContext class constructor you can define it as `this.Database.SetCommandTimeout(180);`. In addition to this, you can even set in your `appsettings.json` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Call `CommandTimeout` on the same instance of `sqlServerOptionsAction` parameter you are using to configure the row paging:

```
services.AddDbContext<RewardsContext>(
options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MembershipContext"),
        b => b.UseRowNumberForPaging().CommandTimeout(60)),
ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```